# Next js not bundling public folder in production

Tags: reactjs, next.js, build

Hi everyone hope you are well, I am trying to build my next js[enter image description here][1] app using the command "next build && next export".
But unfortunately, after completion in the out folder, it just give me "_next" folder.

```js
-- package.json --

{
  "name": "convertingapp",
  "version": "0.1.4",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build && next export",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emailjs/browser": "^3.7.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "next": "12.1.6",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.5.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "react-tilt": "^0.1.4",
    "reactjs-popup": "^2.0.5",
    "save": "^2.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "8.16.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.1.6"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: sorry my friend I am going to edit it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of this issue was next image optimization, I was using the  tag from next and after replacing it with the  tag my problem solved.